# unable to get list of products by using xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-applications

Task- to print all the product description and price from AMAZON
I Used list and iterate them by using for loop

Happen - It only print one product info and price and print them till the for loop matches the condition

Code:

```
List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"s-result-list s-search-results sg-row\"]//descendant::span[@class=\"a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal\"]"));
        int count = products.size();
        System.out.println(count);


    //using XLS reader class to make runtime excel sheet and add column
    Xls_Reader reader = new Xls_Reader(prop.getProperty("Excel"));
    if (!reader.isSheetExist("ProductData")) {
        reader.addSheet("ProductData");
        reader.addColumn("ProductData", "Name of Product");
        reader.addColumn("ProductData", "Price of Product");
    }

    // for loop to set cell data of product description and product price
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        String prod_desc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal\"]")).getText();
        System.out.println("Done111");
        reader.setCellData("ProductData", "Name of Product", i, prod_desc);

        String prod_price= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"a-section a-spacing-none a-text-center\"]//descendant::span[@class=\"a-price-whole\"]"
        )).getText(); System.out.println(prod_price);
        reader.setCellData("ProductData", "Price of Product", i, prod_price);            
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Result:

```
Amazon.in: wrist watches
26
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
Done111
3,746
PASSED: clickOnSearchBtnTest
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It prints only one product info. I have to print to all the products info from a webpage by using for loop

Comment: You have the desc and price scrape inside the for loop but are they changing in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the html.. It will help in solving your problem

In the mean time try following:

```
for(WebElement product : products) {
  product.getText();
}
```

Comment: find only the product description and price  of given items on the first webpage & print them

Answer (score -1):

Using following xpath you will get list of all descriptions from first page

```
List<WebElement> descriptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span[@class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal']"));
```

Using following xpath you will get the list of all prices

```
List<WebElement> prices = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span[@class='a-price-whole']"));
```

As count of both description list and price list will be same therefore, we will iterate the loop and get the text from each element from the both of the lists.

```
for(int i = 0; i < descriptions.size(); i++) {
        String desc = descriptions.get(i).getText();
        String price = prices.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(desc +":"+ price);
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question a code only answer doesn't really explain why you chose that code or how your code solves the problem.